# Is there a standard file format for storing calendar information

Tags: .net, calendar

I have some calendar information (scheduling, appointments, etc). 
Is there a (XML based) file format for this?
If so, Is there a .NET library for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)

[Creating iCal Files in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658/creating-ical-files-in-c)