# Is it possible to add an event to the calendar in Outlook with a webpage form submit in C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007

Is there a way to add a event to outlook, exchange, from a webpage. I would like to add an event to a particular calendar on submit, on the server side with .NET.

The scenario is as follows:
an employ orders coffee for a meeting. An event is created on the cafeteria calendar with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible to do this by constructing an [iCal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) request through code and then emailing that to the cafeteria calendar account.  If there is somebody managing the cafeteria calendar then at least they will see and acknowledge the request first rather than it appear directly into the calendar.

There is probably some managed library somewhere for constructing an iCal file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658/creating-ical-files-in-c)).  In the past, I've simply saved a calendar request to my desktop, opened it up in notepad and then used that as the basis for my meeting requests.  I then have the code replace the relevant bits when it comes to sending the request out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible using [Collaboration Data Objects](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB300GB305&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=collaboration+data+objects).