# send appointment invitation to lotus notes 8.5 clients via c#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus, appointment

i am using Interop.Domino.dll and able to send mail via c# code to lotus notes 8.5 users.
now i want to send appointment invations to users via c# code.

here is my code.

```
   oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Appointment");

                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("AppointmentType", "3");  //  meeting



                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", "Deneme Toplantı");
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("CALENDARDATETIME", StartDate);
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("StartDateTime", StartDate);
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("EndDateTime", EndDate);
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("StartDate", StartDate);

                //oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("MeetingType", "1");
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Required", "xx\\xx.xx");


                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", "xx@xx.com");
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("From", "xx@xx.com");
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "pr.incipal");
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Chair", "erdem.tomus"); 
                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Location", "location test");


                oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Body", an invitation");
                oNotesDocument.ComputeWithForm(true, false);

                oItemValue = oNotesDocument.GetItemValue("SendTo");
                //Send the email
                oNotesDocument.Send(false, ref oItemValue);
```

i am able to send invitation but i wasn'T able to fill the attendees on who part of a lotus notes appointment form. will appreciate help on this.
Infact i need ReplaceItemValue on who property but it didn't work like that.
Thanks

Comment: This makes me think of a related question: "How many organizations still use Lotus Notes?" I wanted to tag this 'wtf-is-lotus-notes,' but the kill-joys always edit that stuff away.

Comment: wish i had the chance to change it men...we are tryin to integrate it with sharepoint,think how hard my job is :)

Comment: I feel your pain. One system I support has W95 clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "EnterSendTo" field is used when the appointment form is open to let the user enter the attendees for the meeting.  I believe that gets translated to the "RequiredAttendees" item on the document once the meeting is sent.

From your code you could try:

```
oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("EnterSendTo", "xx@xx.com");
```

Put that before the call to ComputeWithForm and it should work.  Otherwise, try replacing the value of the RequiredAttendees item and see if that works.

Alternatively, you could send calendar entries using the iCal format.  A quick search on SO led me to this question:  [Creating iCal Files in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658/creating-ical-files-in-c).  It appears there is a decent C# class library you could use to generate iCal files, and Domino mail should recognize them.