# Creating Lotus Notes Appointment with Java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, appointment

I was trying to generate a Lotus Notes Appointment using the Domino Java API DOMINGO. The appointment is created successfully in my local mail database and I was able to open it. But unfortunally there are no required attendees listet in the Appointment. After closing it, my field 'RequiredAttendees' is not there anymore, it has been removed.
I tried to compare an Appointment created manually with a new one I generated by my Java application. The result can be found in the [dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vxaycj88b4rkzum/AJyy1RJK28).

I can not figure out what is missing in my Java-generated Appointment.

Thanks for any help!

PS: I know this question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144041/creating-an-appointment-for-lotus-notes-programmatically). I tried the recommended solution for this problem but it didn't work out...

Comment: You're not likely to get any useful information unless you show your code.  Also, can you please explain why you are using the Domingo API instead of the standard lotus.domino.* Java API?

Comment: Echoing Richards comment. If you are using Domino 9 there is a new LS/Java API call. IIRC it is NotesCalendar/NotesCalendarEntry

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with Java, why not work with the fabulous new [Calendar Services REST API](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-97BAWN)? You can download it directly from OpenNTF.org and have Domino do all the hard work behind the scenes. You can also work with full CRUD (Create, Replace, Update and Delete) support on all other Domino views and documents with the other siebling in Domino REST Services, [Domino Data Services](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#ddapi_ref). The REST-API services open up a whole new world for application developers wanting to interact with Domino data.

Good luck!