# Create Google Calendar Events Using .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I need to create Google Calendar Events using ASP.NET.
Requirement: On click of a button, the event details will be captured like Start Time, End Time, Agenda, Email IDs of attendees and the event will be created in Google Calendar.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a eMail formatted to send to your contact, or anything you want, hope it helps :)

```
public void SendAppointment()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@email.com", "NEW EVENT");
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("no-reply@email.com", "password");
            sc.EnableSsl = true;

            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("invited@mail.com", "Invited"));
            msg.Subject = "Subject";
            msg.Body = "YOUR CONTENT";

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//GeO");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", START_DATE));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", END_DATE));
            str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + Direccion);
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
            //str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", msg.Body));

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", msg.Subject));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            System.Net.Mime.ContentType type = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            type.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            //type.Parameters.Add("method", "PUBLISH");
            type.Parameters.Add("name", "Cita.ics");
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), type));
            sc.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That you want is an iCalendar file. Please look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar.
and here [Creating iCal Files in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658/creating-ical-files-in-c-sharp)